# Python imports: module not found from same level module

Tags: python, import

[image: Folder arrangement]

In the terminal

```
>  python mod1/script1.py
>> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mod2'
```

I have followed the [guide about imports](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) and numerous other stack overflows about htis very basic problem, and I don't get why it's not working. Pylance is able to resolve the modules. - Using Python 3.10.7 64-bit.

Every module has `__init__.py`.

Directory structure as in screencap

```
root
-mod1
--script1.py
--__init__.py
-mod2
--script2.py
--__init__.py
```

Comment: did you append root folder path to PYTHONPATH?

Comment: no I didn't know this was necessary. I would assume that python would search the current directory

Comment: if I execute a script in root, from root it has no problem getting mod2, but when I execute script1 from root it does?

Comment: start by setting PYTHONPATH as suggested let’s see if that helps

Comment: I made PYTHONPATH with the root directory and it did not work

Comment: I only got it to work not by the env, but by doing this import sys,os
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())

Answer (score 0):

you want to import a module from a different directory , am I understood correctly?
so python will only look for the files & modules in its current directory and
you cannot refer to another directory simply by putting the folder name before the module name

- you must import the path of a different directory , using sys module
  so python will look for the module in another path if it doesn't exist in the current path.

  ```
  # import the sys module
  import sys
  # enter the full direction of the package 
  sys.path.insert(0 , 'C:\\Users\\name\\desktop\\folder\\mod2')
  # then import module
  import script2 as lib
  lib.call()
  ```

Comment: Hi so root is the project folder from where I run the scripts but I just had a lot of code so I wanted files within the project to share a library but I don't necessarily want it available to all programs